# Creating a new service in angular.js to send my localstorage model data to a bus?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

So I'm just getting started with Angular Js and have got the basics pretty much nailed.

So i have a form and I am storing the values input by the user to localstorage.

This part is fine but i need to recreate this in a new service to send my data to some .net code written by my colleague...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var applicationHub = $.connection.applicationHub;

        var quoteHub = $.connection.quoteHub;

        var writeShizzles = function(message) {
            $("body").append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
        };


        applicationHub.client.applicationCreated = function(message) {
            writeShizzles(message);
        };

        // noddy app would come from user data obs!
        var noddyApp = {
            primaryApplicant: {
                "firstName": "shizzles",
                "lastName": "lastShizzles",
                "emailAddress": "devteam@ouremail.co.uk",
                "telephoneNumber": "09986576576"
            },
            otherApplicants: [],
            company: {
                "monthlyCardTakings": 50000.01,
                "sector": 1,
                "monthsInBusiness": 24,
                "tradingName": "tradingNameba5f7837-0438-4025-beb1-2324d4f972ff",
                "postcode": "postcodea84d3ce0-9281-4b6c-a5d5-64bb74e66bca"
            },
            "tracking": {}
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            applicationHub.server.createApplication(noddyApp)
                .done(function(result) {
                    writeShizzles("Created App with Id: " + result);

                    applicationHub.server.createAdvance({
                        "applicationId": result,
                        "amount": 50000.10,
                        "cardPercentage": 0.31,
                        "totalRepayment": 55000.60
                    });
                });

            quoteHub.server.getAdvanceLimits()
                .done(function (result) {
                    writeShizzles("AdvanceLimits: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                });

            quoteHub.server.getMaxAdvanceMatrix()
                .done(function (result) {
                    writeShizzles("AdvanceMatrix: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help with this or point me in the right direction please.

thanks in advance

GUIDeveloper

Comment: look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http .You need to create a service to send and receive data from a web service

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i'll take a look now

Comment: Well I basically need to recreate the above javascript in Angular but my javascript and angular is limited so struggling a bit

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i sorted this by just creating a variable of my connection in my controller

```
var applicationHub = $.connection.applicationHub;
```

Then creating a function to pass all of my data stored in localstorage to the hub

```
$scope.createApp = function () {
    var customerApplication = {
        primaryApplicant: {
            "firstName": $localStorage.firstName,
            "lastName": $localStorage.lastName,
            "emailAddress": $localStorage.emailAddress,
            "telephoneNumber": $localStorage.telephoneNumber,
            "offersCheck": $localStorage.offersCheck,
            "offers2Check": $localStorage.worldpayCheck
        },
        otherApplicants: [],
        "tracking": {
            "googleAnalyitics": {
                UtmSource: $localStorage.utmSource,
                UtmMedium: $localStorage.utmMedium,
                UtmCampaign: $localStorage.utmCampaign,
                UtmTerm: $localStorage.utmTerm,
                utmContent: $localStorage.utmContent
            }
        }
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        applicationHub.server.createApplication(customerApplication)
            .done(function (result) {
                $localStorage.applicationId = result;
            });
    });     
};
```